# What is the movie where a crusader comes home and wants to become a farmer must rescue a princess who is protecting a dragon's egg?

Tags: story-identification, movie, dragons

The movie I am looking for is a fantasy movie where at the beginning of the movie you see a dragon kidnap the princess.

You then see a knight come home from the crusades. I believe it takes place in England. His father,a noble, is injured and can't walk. He tells his father and those around about the crusade. He pulls out a fork (but doesn't have a name for it) and says he is going to call it a pitch. He then tells his father that he just wants some land so he can become a farmer. So his father tells him to go to the king because they are old friends.

He goes to the king who is sending people out to find the princess, who is betrothed to some (evil) noble or prince that she doesn't want to marry. The knight tells him of his desire for land to farm and the king tells him if he finds his daughter he will grant him the land.

He eventually finds the princess who doesn't want to leave because she is trying to protect the dragons egg. Eventually they have to fight the evil lord and teh dragon comes back and eats the evil lord.

I believe the movies is from the 90's (I believe mid to late)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the 2004 film *[George and the Dragon](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0306892/plotsummary)*

> The first crusade to free the Holy Land has ended. A mass of weary knights, squires, soldiers of fortune and Priests are making their way home across a Europe that has changed forever. George (James Purefoy), a handsome English knight, unsettled by the horrendous bloodletting he witnessed in Palestine, desires to hang up his sword and settle down to a quiet, peaceful life. On returning to England, he heads north where he's heard the land is good and the population sparse, and of a kindly King named Edgar (Simon Callow). He finds King Edgar in a terrible state. His beautiful daughter, Princess Lunna (Piper Perabo) has recently disappeared. In return for a small plot of land, George agrees to search for Princess Lunna. With Edgar's faithful servant, Elmendorf (Bill Treacher), George sets out. George discovers the Princess and the truth behind her strange disappearance. The quest now set before them ends in a love, a lie, and a legend that has lasted for a thousand years.

[This review](https://lisashea.com/lisabase/writing/medieval/movies/georgeandthedragon.html) mentions the egg.

> They run into a princess who is treated like an inane, spoiled brat. Her sole interest is in protecting a dragon egg - "because it's the last one." That's it, period. When asked, well how about all the villages it will destroy and lives it will slay when it hatches, she doesn't know or care. She has no thoughts. She's obsessive to the point of inanity.

### Trailer

Found with search terms of `site:imdb.com crusader farmer dragon`

Comment: This is the movie. Thank You